# ReactJs how can i add object to array without mutating?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

İn react , Let's say one checkbox is selected and message information is received. I am sending this information to array with setState and I can use this information. What I want is when I click on the second checkbox, I can still get this information, but when I send it to the array, the first selected array is deleted from the array, so I can only see the last one I selected. I want to add all of the ones I chose.

-- Lets say  checkbox1 and checkbox 2 its clicked and take the data inside of them.

> I dont want to do this  => allMessage = [{id:1 , name"xyz"}]
> I want this             => allMessage =[{id:1, name:"xyz"} , {id:2, name:"zlk"}]

```ts
static calculateState(prevState, props) {
  return {
    selectedMessage: []
  }
}

handleCheckbox() {
  const { message } = this.props;

  const values = {
    id: message.rid,
    name: message.date
  }
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    selectedMessage: [values, ...prevState.selectedMessage]
  }));

}
```

[image]

Comment: SetState1, SetState2, useEffect when ever either state changes??

Answer (score 0):

you can use the spread operator:

```js
let array1 = [{name: "oguzhan bay"}]
let array2 = [..array1, {name: "5alidshammout"}]
```

Comment: I take the same results, when another data came up and send it like this first one is deleting. I just see the last one.